# Apply random body class before page is rendered to avoid flicker?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple page:

```
<html>
...
<body class="bg-black">
...
</body>
```

By default, body background color is defined by class `bg-black`. Now, I want page to have a random color. I have a javascript function that uses jQuery and that removes the current class and set the new, random class for background color.

Problem is that there is a flickering: the page first shows the black background (`bg-body`) and then in a few moments the body class is changed by javascript and the random color is applied (i.e. the random class is set).

I want to remove this flickering, i.e. to remove the initial body color.

My javascript is executed after the `</body>`:

```
...
</body>
<script>
    $(function () {initPage();});
</script>
</html>
```

I can't use backend for this. Is there a way to change the class of the body BEFORE the page is rendered?

Comment: @Adriani6 but there must be a way I can do that - I mean, to trick it somehow.

Comment: @Adriani6 That's not true. JavaScript is executed as it is encountered and it can block the UI from rendering. As a simple test, just put an `alert()` in the `head` of any page with content and you won't see the content until after you clear the `alert()`.

Comment: It's not valid to place ***any*** code after `</body>`.

Comment: Reading my comment now - I can see where you're getting the issue. I did word myself wrongly in the last few words.

Comment: How about a CSS transition to make the flickering look better.

Comment: See my updated answer for a working solution with documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is simply because the `body` element begins to render with one color and, because of the location of your `script`, it changes to another color later.

**FYI:** it is invalid to place any code after the `</body>` tag, except the closing `html` tag.

So, the final color needs to be set prior to the `body` element being parsed and that means JavaScript running in the `head` section of the document

Fist, place your `script` in the `head` section. This will allow it to process prior to the `body` tag being encountered. This will result in the background color being established before the `body` tag is parsed and so you won't get one color and then another.

Now, you can't access the `body` element at this point because the parser hasn't reached that element yet, so your JavaScript code can't attempt to change `body`. But, you can have JavaScript dynamically create or modify a pre-existing CSS stylesheet rule using the [CSS Object Model (CSSOM)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information).

Second, don't use the jQuery `$()` (`document.ready()`) pattern. You want the `initPage()` function to run right away. In fact, you really don't want or need to bundle the code up into a function since it only needs to run once and it needs to run as soon as it's encountered.

The following code won't work here in the Stack Overflow code snippet environment, but [here's a link to a CodePen](https://codepen.io/smar1216/pen/jvrXoa) where you can see it working (just refresh the page to see a new color applied).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <style>
    body {
     background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
  
  <script>
    // Possible colors:
    let colors = ["green","yellow","orange","teal","grey"];
    
    // Get reference to stylesheet
    var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[1];
    
    // Pick a random color from the array
    let newColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    
    // Edit the existing stylesheet rule for body to use random color
    stylesheet.cssRules[0].style.backgroundColor = newColor;
  </script>
  
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <h4>
  Hello World
 </h4>
 
</body>
  <script>
 var color=["green","red","yellow","orange","pink"];
    var rand_color= color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = rand_color;
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: `style` is not available at that moment.

Comment: you can set style any time after loading the page.